# How sparse can a matrix mapping between sparse vectors be?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, matrix-analysis, sparse-matrices

Let $s$ and $d$ be non-negative integers with $0\leq s<d$ and let $v,u\in \mathbb{R}^d$ be vectors satisfying the sparsity estimate
$$
\max\{\|u\|_0,\|v\|_0\}\leq d-s,
$$
where, as usual, for any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we define $\|x\|_0:=\sum_{i=1}^d\,I_{x_i\neq 0}$.

Let $A$ be an $d\times d$-matrix solving $Au=v$.   How sparse can $A$ be?  I.e.: what is
$$
\inf_{A\in L(\mathbb{R}^d),\,Au=v}\, \|A\|_0,
$$
where as above $\|A\|_0:=\sum_{i,j=1}^d\,I_{A_{i,j}\neq 0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||v||_0$, so $\leq d-s$: The matrix $A$ needs to have at least one entry for every entry of $v$ (otherwise it can't obtain that entry). It is also sufficient to have so many entries, as if we consider one $j$ with $u_j \not= 0$ (which exists otherwise the system has a solution (the zero matrix) only if $v_i = 0$ for all $i$) then we can set for every entry $v_i \not= 0$ the matrix entry $A_{i,j} = \frac{v_i}{u_j}$.

Comment: Sorry I'm abit confused, what is $A_{i,j}$ when $u_j=0$ or $v_i=0$?

Comment: When $v_i = 0$ then $A_{i,j} = 0$. We can use an arbitrary $u_j \not= 0$ to find such a matrix. If all $u_j = 0$ then this system has a solution only if also all $v_i = 0$.

Comment: I clarified the answer a bit.

Comment: Great!  Thanks Bastian